# Which elite affixes cannot be dodged?

Tags: diablo-iii

Which elite affixes cannot be dodged? 

Clarification: By "dodged", I mean the "dodge" mechanic in the game: when the attack looks like it should hit you, but you dodge it based on your "Dodge Chance" stat.

Quin69 [mentioned in one of his 2.2 Monk guides](https://youtu.be/Zlug6uvSGvo?t=16m52s) that the following are dodge-able:

- Reflect Damage
- Fire Chains
- "so many magic affixes"

and the following are NOT dodge-able:

- Frozen Pulse
- "poison and stuff"

I've been unable to find any further research or proof yet.

I found this for most kinds of damage reduction, but not dodge:
http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/91166-elite-affixes-types-and-damage-reduction-mechanics

Comment: First, your question is unclear. Do you mean "moved out of" or "ignored on successful Dodge roll"? Second, what research did you do?

Comment: There are some items (legendaries or sets) that provide immunity against certain damage affixes. And there are class skills that can do the same.

Comment: @OrcJMR I updated the question to clarify that I mean Dodge, not avoidance. I also included what little info I have found so far. I have found posts describing which they think *should* be able to be dodged, but not which actually are. I'm sure many of the players toward the top of the Monk leaderboards know this, but I've been unable to find a list.

Comment: @pfayze Ah, okay. As a DH, I have almost forgotten what it is like to Dodge things now... One of more important things I remember dodgeable, though, were Frozen blasts and Izual's nova.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**

Diablofans topic is from 2012, mostly outdated

## Things Dodge DOES affect

- Ranged and melee basic attacks (except Mallet Lords) Most single-hit spells (such as Morlu Incinerator meteor impacts and Lacuni firebombs)
- Electrified
- Frozen Pulse
- Frozen (Explosion)
- Jailer
- Molten (Explosion)
- Mortar
- Thunderstorm
- Fire Chains (partially: separate ticks are dodged, the whole DoT - not dodgeable)

## Things Dodge DOES NOT affect

- Mallet Lord basic attacks
- All ground-based boss and monster affixes (such as Herald of Pestilence (Blighter) ground-aids)
- Arcane
- Desecrator
- Frozen (Persistent ground effect)
- Knockback (Assuming you get hit by an attack)
- Molten (Persistent ground effect)
- Nightmarish (Same as Knockback)
- Plagued
- Poison Enchanted
- Reflect Damage
- Vortex
- Wormhole